# How to access to RESTController through a controller?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring.

The method in my RESTController is this,
http://localhost:8080/delivery-api/training/submit. It is able to save hard code values into database.

This is part of my html form, it can be open up using this URL: http://localhost:8080/delivery-web/training/apply.

```
<form th:object="${applyForm}" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/delivery-api/training/submit" >



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"
                            for="form-field-1" > Country </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" id="form-field-1" placeholder="Country"
                                class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7" th:field="*{country}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"
                            for="form-field-1"> Fee </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" id="form-field-1" th:field="*{Fee}"              class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"
                            for="form-field-1"> Start Date </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" id="form-field-1" th:field="*{startDate}"

                                class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"
                            for="form-field-1">End Date </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" id="form-field-1" th:field="*{endDate}"

                                class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <br> <br>

                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-110"></i> Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

When I click on submit, it can be directed to  http://localhost:8080/delivery-api/training/submit and insert the hard coded values into database, but it did not direct to my application-form.html page after that.

My controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/apply")
    public String apply(@Valid @ModelAttribute("applyForm") DeliveryApplicationForm applyForm, BindingResult errors, Model model) {


        model.addAttribute("applyForm", applyForm);


        return VIEW_PATH + "application-form";
    }
```

I would like to render html page and also pass data from my form to RESTController method through a controller after I click on the submit button in my html page.

May I know how I can do it?

Comment: Seems its be `CORS` issue.

Comment: any advice on how I can do it?

Comment: As you used spring so, add a filter say `CORSFilter.java` and add a header in response `Allow-access-control-origin: *`. You can google it how to do that.